Best practice for unused pins
I have a 74LS74 S-R Latch (Dual D-Type Flip-Flop).  I'm only using one of the flip-flops though.
What's best practice for the unused pins?  Should I ground them all, connect them together, connect them to Vcc?
Datasheet

If you look at the typical i/o section you might see a pull-up/pull-down resistor (maybe multiple) depending if it is an input or output. This is only true of the 74 series. Transistors are kind of more flexible than Mosfets.

It depends on the pin and on the specific flavor of TTL in use.
For unused inputs:

CMOS (HC, HCT, AC, ACT, LVC, etc.) Tie to GND or Vcc as needed.
Bipolar TTL (LS, ALS, AS, F, etc.): Tie to GND or Vcc as needed. Optional for tie-high: use pull-up resistor (10k normally) for backwards compatibility with legacy TTL.
Legacy bipolar TTL (74xx, 74Sxx): Tie to GND directly or to Vcc via mandatory pull-up.**

For the specific device, 74xx74, the unused PREn and CLRn inputs should be tied inactive (high). Unused D and CLK can be tied high or low; with TTL tying high will use less power.
Now, here's the thing about bipolar TTL. Any LS, S, 74xx TTL input that isn't connected to anything will appear as '1' to the logic, as there is internal biasing that pulls it up. As a result you'll see many schematics where they simply left the unused inputs unconnected.
For a prototype that's probably ok. For a production board, leaving unconnected inputs isn't the best practice, as noise can couple to the input and cause unwanted behavior (like weird ESD events for example.) Best to tie them.
Finally, some design houses even mandate 'soft' (resistor) pullup/pulldowns on all unused pins for complete chip-by-chip testability. More commonly, good practice is to use soft pulldowns for tristate enables, making automated test easier.
** Several legacy TTL families (74xx, 74Sxx) require a pull-up to Vcc to protect multiple-emitter inputs from exceeding 5.5V. To be certain, never tie 74Sxx or 74xx inputs directly to Vcc. Always use a pull-up (refer to https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sdya009c/sdya009c.pdf, pp.7.) Direct to GND is ok.

Thanks, this is a 74LS74 so just ground the GND then?

for LS74, PREn, CLRn, CLK and D can all be tied to Vcc, optionally through a pull-up.

Thanks.  I'm a little short on space, will bad things happen if I connect them directly?

Only if you substitute a 74S74 or plain 7474. That said, you should be using HCT.


Do what the datasheet recommends for unused inputs. Outputs don't need to be connected to anything.

If the datasheet doesn't address unused inputs, then it's best to tie them (via resistor) to the voltage that uses the least amount of power.


As noted in other answers, you can omit the resistor if you know your specific logic type, but I regard that as an optimization. Using the resistors allows for easier rework and changes if needed.

Outputs Do matter - they should be left open, and must definitely not be connected to Vcc or GND.

I was just about to say the same.  Perhaps "Outputs do not require termination, and should never be simply shorted to ground or power" would be a bit better.

@PeterBennett Point taken. I meant don't matter as in can be left alone. But I'll update for this.
